# How to get the access level of a user for a bitbucket repo using REST API?

Tags: bitbucket, bitbucket-api, bitbucket-cloud

Hey I am using REST API for bit-bucket cloud for my application. I have to check whether the user(with token, which is passed through header) has access to a particular repo or not? If yes what access level is provided? What url should I hit for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can hit [this](https://api.bitbucket.org/2.0/user/permissions/repositories?q=repository.name=%22%3CrepoName%3E%22) api, with corresponding authToken as header to get the access level. Hope this helps.